# Custom Php RESET Login API works strange?

Tags: php, android, email, android-volley, reset-password

I have a strange issue don't know why it is happening. Actually i have a very simple login API in PHP which takes 2 parameters in where clause username and password and search for specific result.I'm using Android Volley library to handle the post request. Everything works perfect as i thought i send a POST request and my API return JSON data. 
And now the strange part is that this whole process works smoothly as it seems on my all android devices but my client is in UK and when he try to login surprisingly my php code returns no record found!!!

This is my PHP Script:

```
function ShowDriverRecord($userName, $password) {
    global $connect;
    $query = "SELECT drv_id,drv_firstname,drv_surname FROM wp_booking_drivers WHERE drv_username = '$userName' AND drv_password = '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $status = false;
    $driverId = null;
    $driverName = null;

    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        $driverRecord = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $status = true;
        $driverId = $driverRecord['drv_id'];
        $driverName = $driverRecord['drv_firstname']." ".$driverRecord['drv_surname'];
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("Status"=>$status,"DriverId"=>$driverId,"DriverName"=>$driverName));
}
```

Java (Android Volley):

```
 Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("userName",username);
    params.put("password",password);
    CustomJsonRequest jsonRequest = new CustomJsonRequest(Request.Method.POST, WebUrls.DRIVER_LOGIN_URL, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                boolean status = response.getBoolean("Status");
                if (status){
                    callbacks.onSuccess(response);
                }else {
                    callbacks.onFailure("Wrong username or password.");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
});
requestQueue.add(jsonRequest);
```

I have web hosting on 123-reg.com- Please tell me whats happening there??
I'm in Pakistan and when i tried to login it works but when my client who's in UK try to login with same credentials it found no record...
Thanks.